# how to loop through the same indexed row and column number from two separate Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, location, row

I have two separate Pandas Dataframes with the same dimensions.

df1

|  | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "A" | "B" | "C" |
| 2 | "A" | "B" | "C" |
| 3 | "A" | "B" | "C" |

df2

|  | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "E" | "A" | "C" |
| 2 | "E" | "F" | "G" |
| 3 | "H" | "I" | "J" |

How can I loop through all df1 row 1 and search for: "A". If "A" is found then take the row and column index and look in df2 for what is in that cell. In this case it would be "E".

I have tried:

```
for row in df1:
   if row.columns contains "A":
       col_marker = column index
       search df2 @ col_marker for whats in that cell...

   else: 
       continue
```

I am expecting the for loop to search each row of df1, find "A" then take that location and search df2 at the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `iterrows()` method is used to loop through the rows of `df1`. For each row, the row index is used to access the same row in `df2` with the `loc` method.

```
# Loop through the rows of df1
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # Check if "A" is in the row
    if "A" in row.values:
        # Get the value in the same row and column in df2
        value = df2.loc[index, "column1"]
        print(value)
```

```
E
E
H
```

You can also use `df2[df1 == "A"]` if you prefer the following output.

| index | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | E | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | E | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | H | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
out = df1.mask(df1.eq('A'), df2)
```

Output:

```
  column1 column2 column3
1       E       B       C
2       E       B       C
3       H       B       C
```

Or for in place modification:

```
df1[df1.eq('A')] = df2
```

Modified `df1`:

```
  column1 column2 column3
1       E       B       C
2       E       B       C
3       H       B       C
```

If you just want to know what's in `df2` without assigning:

```
df2[df1.eq('A')]
```

Output:

```
  column1 column2 column3
1       E     NaN     NaN
2       E     NaN     NaN
3       H     NaN     NaN
```